# Is there a proving of $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{1.5-\frac{(a_n^2-6)^2}{32}}$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Is there a proving of $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{1.5-\displaystyle \frac{(a_n^2-6)^2}{32}}?$$
the above formula gives $\sqrt{2}$

We know that the main formula of finding any square root of number depends on the Newton-Raphson Method. I know how it came, but for my formula I couldn't know how to prove it.
When I checked it, I found it more convergence than Newton-Method, so if there is somebody to help me about the proving.

Some results of finding $\sqrt{2}$

$$a_{1}=\frac{1}{1.5-\displaystyle \frac{(1^2-6)^2}{32}}=\frac{32}{23}?$$
$$a_{2}=\frac{32/23}{1.5-\displaystyle \frac{((32/23)^2-6)^2}{32}}=1.414210519?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1.5-\frac{(x^2-6)^2}{32}}=\frac{32x}{48-(x^2-6)^2}$. Then $f(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt 2$ and $f'(\sqrt 2)=0$, hence the recursion $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ converges at least quadratic to $\sqrt 2$ for $a_0$ sufficiently close.
Upon closer inspection, $f''(\sqrt2)=0$ as well, so we even have cubic convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\sqrt{2}(1+b_n)$. Your formula is $$1+b_{n+1}=\frac{1+b_n}{1.5-\frac{((1+b_n)^2-3)^2}{8}}\\
=\frac{8(1+b_n)}{8+8b_n-4b_n^3-b_n^4}\\
b_{n+1}=\frac{4b_n^3+b_n^4}{8+8b_n-4b_n^3-b_n^4}$$
which is cubic as Hagen says.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to get third order convergence is via Halley`s method. The fastest way to derive its equation is to apply Newton's method to the modified function $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{|f'(x)|}}.$$

In the case of $f(x)=x^p-a$ this leads, up to constant factors, to $$g(x)=x^{(p+1)/2}-ax^{-(p-1)/2}$$ with $$g'(x)=\frac{p+1}2x^{(p-1)/2}+\frac{p-1}2 x^{-(p+1)/2}.$$
The resulting iteration is
$$
x_+=x·\frac{(p-1)x^p+(p+1)a}{(p+1)x^p+(p-1)a}
$$